# What does "cutting in" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, prepositional-phrases

Flies, bees, beetles, wasps, and other insects are segmented creatures——head, thorax, and abdomen. where these parts join, there appears to the imaginative eye a "**cutting in**" of the body.

What does "cutting in" mean in this sentence?

Comment: Isn't that an interruption?

Comment: Presumably, that the body narrows sharply (the proverbial 'wasp waist').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segmentation is the division of something into noticeable segments, such as the tripart setup of head, abdomen and thorax seen in thousands of insects worldwide. Usually, this coincides with a moveable joint or a point of flexibility. The visual representation of this is a narrowing of diameter at the point of segmentation.

The writer is speaking metaphorically about the narrower width of the creature like one might speak of a cut on a lathe: it is metaphorically removing a wedge of material evenly around the diameter such that it looks 'cut' into.